# Problem adding a Site Script and Site Design at hub

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx

We are trying to create a site design with SharePoint document library with folders and sub folders along with custom permissions.
I know how to create a document library but not sure how can i create a folders and sub folders and add Custom permissions in the JSON Schema
Any help is appreciated

```
$adminUPN="admin user name"
$orgName="mytest"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com/ -Credential $userCredential

$docscript='{
"$schema": "schema.json",
"actions": [
    {
        "verb": "createSiteColumn",
        "fieldType": "Text",
        "internalName": "siteColumn1Text",
        "displayName": "Project Status", 
        "isRequired": false,
        "group": "Contoso Custom",
        "enforceUnique": true
    },
    {
        "verb": "createSiteColumn",
        "fieldType": "Number",
        "internalName": "siteColumn2Number",
        "displayName": "Effort in Days",
        "isRequired": false
    },
    {
        "verb": "createSiteColumn",
        "fieldType": "Note",
        "internalName": "siteColumn3Note",
        "displayName": "Meeting Notes",
        "isRequired": false
    },
    {
        "verb": "createSiteColumn",
        "fieldType": "User",
        "internalName": "siteColumn4User",
        "displayName": "Project Owner",
        "isRequired": false
    },
    {
        "verb": "createContentType",
        "name": "Contoso Projects",
        "description": "custom list content type",
        "parentName": "Item",
        "hidden": false,
        "subactions":
        [
            {
                "verb": "addSiteColumn",
                "internalName": "siteColumn1Text"
            },
            {
                "verb": "addSiteColumn",
                "internalName": "siteColumn2Number"
            },
            {
                "verb": "addSiteColumn",
                "internalName": "siteColumn3Note"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "verb": "createSPList",
        "listName": "MytestLibrary",
        "templateType": 101,
        "subactions": 
        [
            {
                "verb": "setDescription",
                "description": "Custom document library to illustrate SharePoint site scripting capabilities - spring 2018"
            },
            {
                "verb": "addContentType",
                "name": "Contoso Projects"
            },
            {
                "verb": "addSiteColumn",
                "internalName": "siteColumn4User",
                "addToDefaultView": true
            },
            {
                "verb": "addSPField",
                "fieldType": "DateTime",
                "displayName": "Delivery Date",
                "internalName": "spField1DateTime",
                "isRequired": true,
                "addToDefaultView": true
            },
            {
                "verb": "addSPView",
                "name": "Contoso Projects by Effort",
                "viewFields": 
                [
                    "ID", 
                    "Title",
                    "siteColumn1Text",
                    "siteColumn2Number",
                    "siteColumn3Note",
                    "siteColumn4User",
                    "spField1DateTime"
                ],
                "query": "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><FieldRef Name=\"siteColumn1Text\" Ascending=\"FALSE\" /></OrderBy><Where><Gt><FieldRef Name=\"siteColumn2Number\"/><Value Type=\"Number\">5</Value></Gt></Where>",
                "rowLimit": 100,
                "isPaged": true,
                "makeDefault": true
            }
        ]
    }
],
"bindata": { },
"version": 1
```

}'

```
Add-SPOSiteScript  -Title "Custom Libray" -Content $docscript -Description "Creates library for tracking customer contact information"
Add-SPOSiteDesign -Title "Contoso customer tracking" -WebTemplate "64" -SiteScripts "b0179831-f9a3-47c5-8476-eb6113e9bcef" -Description "Tracks key customer data in a library"
```

Answer (score 0):

Files/Folders provisioning as well as creating custom permissions for List and Libraries is not supported yet via Site Scripts.

Reference - [Site Design JSON Schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema)

Comment: Can we use flow to create folder and then apply the schema https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema#trigger-a-flow

Comment: Yes via flow you can do that. But you will have to create HTTP request yourself for each folder/subfolder and for custom permissions as well. So, you can create a Site script which will trigger flow and then perform these actions